# Distribution of difference of first hitting times of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Suppose $T_x=\inf \{ t \mid W_t = x\}$. Where $(W_t)$ is a standard Wiener process. What is the distribution of $$T_a-T_{b}$$ for $a, b\in\mathbb R$?
Does it have any relation to $T_{a-b}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming that $0<b<a$, the random variables $T_a-T_b$ and $T_{a-b}$ have the same distribution. This follows from the strong Markov property of Brownian motion at time $T_b$. Note that if $b<0<a$ then $T_a-T_b$ is negative with positive probability.